# What is this specific UX element called?

Tags: scrolling, wordpress

The new [Apple Pencil](https://www.apple.com/in/apple-pencil/) site has an above the fold introductory element where it says "Its only a ... pencil/scalpel/note-taker..." and this scrolls like a slot machine. What is this effect called? I've seen different implementations of this on different websites but could never really figure out what its called.

Comment: Software/plugin/etc recommendations are off-topic on this site. Element identifications are more suited here, so you should edit your question.

Comment: Edited my question to remove the ask for a plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By going to your browsers "Developer Tools" you are able to view the HTML/CSS for elements on the page.

After inspecting this element on their site suggests that they call it **Word Reel**.

[image]

Comment: Edited because although you provided the correct answer, it's good form to give a little extra explanation.

Comment: @julian Oh, no, this is definitively wrong! "Word Real" it is just the name of the class. There is just an animation, using a translate3d() CSS function...

Comment: I disagree with this answer. The question is, "What is the effect called?" but the answer is what the developer named it, not what every UX developer would necessarily know it as, though I think "word reel" is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in a comment to the answer that was chosen as the right one, I think it is a confusion. "Word real" it is just a random name for the class. It is just an animation there, using a translate3d() CSS function.

I think a suggestive name could be "3D Scrolling Text in CSS3". A similar effect is used in this example that simulates the Star Wars opening crawl.

http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/css3-starwars/index.html